# Golang - String with many delimiters to slice or struct

Tags: go

I have the following string returned as response from a TCP connection :

```
220 Connected.\ncommand:connect\nemail:ERROR_MAIL_MISSING\nstatus:CMD_ERROR\nend
```

I want actually to transform this response to the following golang struct :

```
type Message struct {
    Key string
    Value string
}

type Response struct {
    Connect string
    Messages []Message
}
```

If 220 Connected is always present means :

```
Response.Connect => TRUE
```

All response between 220 Connected. and end can be accessed using :

```
Response[0].Key => "command"
Response[0].Value => "connect"
```

This is what I actually achieved :

```
result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
        data := strings.Split(string(result), "\n")

        for i := range data {
                Reply := new(Response)
                if data[i] == "220 Connected." {
                        Reply.Connect = "TRUE"
                        Response = append(Response, Reply)
                }
        }
```

Any hint how this can be achieved ? I'm a newbie with Golang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a bit more work to extract the data you want. Here's a sample program that correctly populates the `Messages` array. I'll update with some notes on what's I did to move from your attempt to what you're looking for.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"


type Message struct {
    Key string
    Value string
}

type Response struct {
    Connect string
    Messages []Message
}
func main() {
    result := `220 Connected.\ncommand:connect\nemail:ERROR_MAIL_MISSING\nstatus:CMD_ERROR\nend`
        data := strings.Split(string(result), "\\")

    r := &Response{}
        for i := range data {
                if data[i] == "220 Connected." {
                        r.Connect = "TRUE"
                } else {
            tokens := strings.Split(data[i], ":")
            if len(tokens) == 2 {
                m := Message{tokens[0], tokens[1]}
                r.Messages = append(r.Messages, m)
            }
        }
        }
        for i := range r.Messages {
             fmt.Println(r.Messages[i])
        }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Hs8aqYPyuM

Alright, so first lets list some problems. In your attempt the for loop looks like this;

```
  for i := range data {
            Reply := new(Response)
            if data[i] == "220 Connected." {
                    Reply.Connect = "TRUE"
                    Response = append(Response, Reply)
            }
    }
```

This isn't consistent with your types/data layout. On every iteration you create a new `Response` instance, you actually only need one. What you want on each iteration is a new `Message` instance. This causes a few problems, firstly the data you're looking at isn't a response, it's a message, secondly you keep overwriting the previous one (that object is only scoped for the loop). To correct this we instantiate the `Response` object before the loop. Secondly, you need a second split in order to get your data out. So inside the loop we split on a colon to separate the key and value of each message. Then I have a quick check on the length before adding it (I got a panic on first run, the first if probably failed, meaning you need to edit that a bit. If you don't get 220 for connected you want to set that value to false, you should do the message split an a final else but simply not being `220 Connected.` isn't sufficient to assume the current item is a `Message` which is why I added bounds check). Note that inside this loop I instantiate a new message for each key value pair. We use append there to append to the `Messages` array, not appending `Response`'s onto eachother (that will never work since it's a struct, not a slice or map). This also makes it so the `Message` persists rather than going out of scope each time we hit the bottom of the loop (`m` will go out of scope but the instance in `r.Messages` will still be around).